# LINQ - 'the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a complex LINQ to SQL to query, which joins onto two tables - one is rather simple and works fine, but one is fairly complex and I'm getting `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin`

It's a rather long query, and I do development on a work with Internet access so I thought I'd see if the line that seems to be the issue is enough:

```
join consignments in dc.Consignments
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TripDate > dateFrom 
    && x.TripDate < dateTo 
    && x.DeliveryDepot == depot.Letter 
    && (x.DeliveryStatus == 2 || x.DeliveryStatus == 3))
  on new { Reg = s.VehicleReg, Depot = s.VehicleDepot } 
      equals new { Reg = consignments.VehicleReg, Depot = consignments.DeliveryDepot }
  into con
```

I've ensured that the data types are the same, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks all, well after looking a bit more, one of the Depot datatypes is 'char(2)', and another is 'nchar(10)'. Would that cause this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you sure that s.VehiculeDepot is the same type as consignments.DeliveryDepot ?

```
on new { Reg = s.VehicleReg, Depot = s.VehicleDepot } 
equals new { Reg = consignments.VehicleReg, Depot = consignments.DeliveryDepot }
```

Comment: This was causing me much headache until I assigned a Type to each item. `{ID = something.Id} equals {ID = otherthing.Id}` where ID is the Type

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is in this part:

```
on new { Reg = s.VehicleReg, Depot = s.VehicleDepot }
   equals
   new { Reg = consignments.VehicleReg, Depot = consignments.DeliveryDepot }
```

Make sure that `s.VehicleReg` has the same type as `consignments.VehicleReg`, and `s.VehicleDepot` has the same type as `consignments.DeliveryDepot`.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your member names are exactly the same and same case. For example:

```
 new { Reg = s.VehicleReg, Depot = s.VehicleDepot }
   equals
   new { Reg = consignments.VehicleReg, DEpot = consignments.DeliveryDepot }
```

would fail because depot is different case in the second anonymous type.